# Show that $x_n= ((-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}n^2)/3n^2$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that $$x_n= \frac{(-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}n^2}{3n^2}$$ diverges
Does the proof like this? ?
Let $x_{2k}$ be subsequence of $x_n$
$X_{2k} = 1/2k^2 -1/3$ then then it is converges to $-1/3 $
Let $x(2k-1)$ be subsequence of $x_n$
$$X(2k-1)= \frac{-1}{3 (2k-1)^2} + 1/3 $$
Then it is converges to $1/3$ 
Tow different subsequences limit
So $x_n$ divergent
And can I use squeeze theorem to prove $x_n$ ??

Answer (score 1):

The given sequence may be expressed as a *sum* of a *convergent sequence* and a *divergent sequence*
$$
x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{3n^2}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3}
$$ thus it *diverges*.

Comment: More few detail please

Comment: Sure. We have, as $n \to \infty$, $\frac{(-1)^n}{3n^2} \to 0$, then it is a convergent sequence. But $v_n:=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3}$ does not admit any limit, the terms oscillate $-1/3,+1/3,-1/3,\ldots$.

Comment: Oh yah I understood that thanks :)